# Function returning the code to create a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking for a function to get the code generating a data frame in R. I haven't found any simple function that would allow me to do this. Of course I could hard code something to do it. I was wondering if there were any shortcut or built-in t  do that.

```
mydata = data.frame(x=c("A","A","B"),y=c(1,2,1))
```

Input:

```
mydata
  x y
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 B 1
```

Ouput:

```
dfToCode(mydata)
"data.frame(x=c("A","A","B"),y=c(1,2,1))"
```

I know it is a little unconventional and that it would be better to store the data frame in a file.
Anyway a function like this would allow me to get a reproducible example of a small data frame easily within my code.

Thank you

Comment: A function that *would allow me [you] to reproducible example of small data frame easily within my [your] code* is `dput`. It is meant for that.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I could not find it