# Count rows in data table with certain values by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a a data table that somewhat looks like this:

```
Property    Type
1           apartment
1           office
2           office
2           office
3           apartment
3           apartment
3           office
```

I now want to count offices and apartments by property:

```
Property    Type       number_of_offices    number_of_apartments
       1    apartment                  1                       1
       1    office                     1                       1
       2    office                     2                       0
       2    office                     2                       0
       3    apartment                  1                       2
       3    apartment                  1                       2
       3    office                     1                       2
```

I tried

```
my.DT <- myDT[,.(Type=Type, number_of_offices=nrow(my.DT[my.DT$Type=="office",]), number_of_apartments=nrow(my.DT$Type=="apparment",], by="Property")
```

However, this only gives me the total counts for the whole data table. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hi laser.p , welcome to SO! To make your questions easier to answer you can follow these guidelines on how to make a good reproducible example in R: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49860402/1870254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it as follows:

```
cols <- c("number_of_offices", "number_of_apartments")
df[, (cols) := .(sum(Type == "office"), sum(Type == "apartment")), Property]

# Property      Type number_of_offices number_of_apartments
# 1:        1 apartment                 1                    1
# 2:        1    office                 1                    1
# 3:        2    office                 2                    0
# 4:        2    office                 2                    0
# 5:        3 apartment                 1                    2
# 6:        3 apartment                 1                    2
# 7:        3    office                 1                    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason why you want to merge the grouped counts with `my.df`?

You can try this, which will give you the counts grouped by `Property` and `Type`. Then merge with the original `myDT`:

```
grouped = myDT[, .N, by=c('Property','Type')]
myDT = merge(myDT, grouped[Type == 'apartment', list(Property,N)], by='Property', all.x=TRUE)
myDT = merge(myDT, grouped[Type == 'office', list(Property,N)], by='Property', all.x=TRUE)
setnames(myDT, c('N.x','N.y'), c('Number of appartments','Number of offices'))
myDT[is.na(myDT)] <- 0

> myDT
   Property      Type Number of appartments Number of offices
1:        1 apartment                     1                 1
2:        1    office                     1                 1
3:        2    office                     0                 2
4:        2    office                     0                 2
5:        3 apartment                     2                 1
6:        3 apartment                     2                 1
7:        3    office                     2                 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This yields the correct numbers, which is already a step forward.

The reason for merging it with my.df is that I later want to merge it with a much larger list. That list has one row per property with a lot of columns containing information (e.g. number of offices and appartments, etc.).

Comment: I edited the answer slightly. I added a left join to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a good start!

```
my.DT <- myDT[,.(Type=Type, number_of_offices=nrow(my.DT[my.DT$Type=="office",]), number_of_apartments=nrow(my.DT$Type=="apparment",], by="Property")
```

The brackets don't match, I assume there was some copy-paste error. These can efficiently avoided by following the [guidelines on how to create a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49860402/1870254) & `reprex` package. The code in your question could then look something like this:

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.2

rooms_dt <- fread(text =
"Property    Type
1           apartment
1           office
2           office
2           office
3           apartment
3           apartment
3           office
")
rooms_dt[, .(
  Type=Type, 
  number_of_offices=nrow(rooms_dt[rooms_dt$Type=="office",]), 
  number_of_apartments=nrow(rooms_dt[rooms_dt$Type=="apartment",])
), by="Property"]
#>    Property      Type number_of_offices number_of_apartments
#> 1:        1 apartment                 4                    3
#> 2:        1    office                 4                    3
#> 3:        2    office                 4                    3
#> 4:        2    office                 4                    3
#> 5:        3 apartment                 4                    3
#> 6:        3 apartment                 4                    3
#> 7:        3    office                 4                    3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you noticed, the problem with that approach is that the `j` expression that gets evaluated for every group (= every `Property`) the numbers of *all* apartment/office rows are counted not just the one of the current `Property`. This could be avoided by subsetting not only for the correct type but also the correct property (available in `j` as the special variable `.BY`). This already yields the desired result:

```r
rooms_dt[, .(
  Type=Type, 
  number_of_offices=nrow(rooms_dt[rooms_dt$Property == .BY & rooms_dt$Type=="office",]), 
  number_of_apartments=nrow(rooms_dt[rooms_dt$Property == .BY & rooms_dt$Type=="apartment",])
), by="Property"]
#>    Property      Type number_of_offices number_of_apartments
#> 1:        1 apartment                 1                    1
#> 2:        1    office                 1                    1
#> 3:        2    office                 2                    0
#> 4:        2    office                 2                    0
#> 5:        3 apartment                 1                    2
#> 6:        3 apartment                 1                    2
#> 7:        3    office                 1                    2
```

However, this solution can be simplified quite a bit:
First and foremost, the columns of the `data.table` can be accessed directly by their name within `[]`:

```r
rooms_dt[, .(
  Type=Type,
  number_of_offices=nrow(rooms_dt[Property == .BY & Type=="office",]),
  number_of_apartments=nrow(rooms_dt[Property == .BY & Type=="apartment",])
), by="Property"]
```

Furthermore, `data.table` provides the current data.table subsetted [sic] to the current group as `.SD`, which allows to simplify this further:

```r
rooms_dt[, .(
  Type=Type,
  number_of_offices=nrow(.SD[Type=="office",]),
  number_of_apartments=nrow(.SD[Type=="apartment",])
), by="Property"]
```

Since not only .SD is subsetted, but all columns are, it is even simpler to just work with them directly:

```r
rooms_dt[, .(
  Type = Type,
  number_of_offices = sum(Type=="office"),
  number_of_apartments = sum(Type=="apartment")
), by="Property"]
```

One of the strengths of `data.table` is that in contrast to most `R` stuff is, that they are mutable. This allows to just add the new columns directly to the old data.table without creating a new one:

```r
rooms_dt[, number_of_offices := sum(Type=="office"), by="Property"]
rooms_dt[, number_of_apartments := sum(Type=="apartment"), by="Property"]
```

This culd also be written as:

```r
rooms_dt[, c("number_of_offices", "number_of_apartments") := list(sum(Type=="office"), sum(Type=="apartment")), by="Property"]
```

or as :

```r
rooms_dt[, `:=`(number_of_offices = sum(Type=="office"), number_of_apartments = sum(Type=="apartment")), by="Property"]
```

---

This was not as easy as it could be, probably because it is rearly needed, often it is desirable to have one of these instead:

```r
rooms_dt[, count_in_property := .N, by=.(Property, Type)]
rooms_dt
#>    Property      Type number_in_property
#> 1:        1 apartment                  1
#> 2:        1    office                  1
#> 3:        2    office                  2
#> 4:        2    office                  2
#> 5:        3 apartment                  2
#> 6:        3 apartment                  2
#> 7:        3    office                  1
```

or

```r
dcast(rooms_dt[, .(number_of = .N), by=.(Property, Type)], Property ~ Type, fill = 0)
#> Using 'number_of' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
#>    Property apartment office
#> 1:        1         1      1
#> 2:        2         0      2
#> 3:        3         2      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `data.table` way to do this for more than two room types, I think:

```
dcast(
  rooms_dt[, .(number_of=.N), by=.(Property, Type)], 
  Property ~ Type, 
  fill=0
)[rooms_dt, on=.(Type)]
```

Full example:

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.6.2
rooms_dt <- fread(text =
                    "Property    Type
1           apartment
1           office
2           office
2           office
3           apartment
3           apartment
3           office
")

rooms_summary_dt <- rooms_dt[, .(number_rooms_of_type_at_property = .N), by=.(Property, Type)]
rooms_summary_dt
#>    Property      Type number_rooms_of_type_at_property
#> 1:        1 apartment                                1
#> 2:        1    office                                1
#> 3:        2    office                                2
#> 4:        3 apartment                                2
#> 5:        3    office                                1

properties_dt <- dcast(rooms_summary_dt, Property ~ Type, fill = 0)
#> Using 'number_rooms_of_type_at_property' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
properties_dt
#>    Property apartment office
#> 1:        1         1      1
#> 2:        2         0      2
#> 3:        3         2      1

properties_dt[rooms_dt, on=.(Property)]
#>    Property apartment office      Type
#> 1:        1         1      1 apartment
#> 2:        1         1      1    office
#> 3:        2         0      2    office
#> 4:        2         0      2    office
#> 5:        3         2      1 apartment
#> 6:        3         2      1 apartment
#> 7:        3         2      1    office
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Here is the dplyr/tidyr solution,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 count() %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = n) %>% 
 left_join(., df, by = 'Property')
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
> # Groups:   Property [3]
>   Property apartment office Type     
>      <int>     <int>  <int> <fct>    
> 1        1         1      1 apartment
> 2        1         1      1 office   
> 3        2        NA      2 office   
> 4        2        NA      2 office   
> 5        3         2      1 apartment
> 6        3         2      1 apartment
> 7        3         2      1 office
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Property = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("apartment", "office"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```